# Transpile into ES 5 using babel by gulp-watch not working

Tags: javascript, gulp, ecmascript-6, gulp-watch, babeljs

I am new to gulp.I am trying to setup a watch so that my src/main.js file is transpiled to dist/main.js file. The Gulpfile has the following code

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var paths = {
    babel:"src/main.js"
}

gulp.task('babel', function() {
    return gulp.src(paths.babel)
        .pipe(watch(paths.babel))
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'))
})
gulp.task('default', ['babel']);
```

My dist/main.js file does not reflect changes from src/main.js . Any help as to where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

Comment: I am on win 8.1 on node 10.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following (and make sure you execute `gulp watch`, not just `gulp`):

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var rimraf = require('rimraf');
var paths = {
  babel: 'src/main.js',
  build: 'dist'
};

gulp.task('clean', function(cb) {
  rimraf(paths.build, cb);
});

gulp.task('build', ['clean'], function() {
  return gulp
    .src(paths.babel)
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.build));
});

gulp.task('watch', ['build'], function() {
  return watch(paths.babel, function() {
    gulp.start('build');
  });
});

gulp.task('default', ['build']);
```

If that doesn't work, maybe your `paths.babel` is wrong. Try changing it to `src/**/*.js`.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the 'clean' task?

Comment: @sfletche Every time `build` runs, the `clean` task will destroy all of the files from the previous `build`. It's just a precautionary measure to ensure that the `dist` directory is always "pristine" and doesn't contain a bunch of accumulated cruft, which is recommended if you plan to serve it on the Web.

Answer (score 0):

the babel task and watch task are separate:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var watch = require('gulp-watch');
var paths = {
    babel:"src/main.js"
};

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.babel, ['babel']);
});

gulp.task('babel', function() {
   gulp.src(paths.babel)
        .pipe(babel())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

`watch` will execute `babel` when it detects a change to `"src/main.js"`

Comment: What version of gulp? There's a watch bug on 3.4. Try wildcarding paths `babel: 'src/*.js'`

Comment: 3.8.11. babel : 5.0.9  . Tried that to no avail .Also tried running webstorm cmd prompt as administrator to no avail. :(

Comment: what isn't working? Are you getting any errors? Does the plain babel task work?

Comment: No errors. Babel task works for the first time, on change of js files, it does not work.

Comment: Oops... Using `gulp.watch` (which should work) instead of `watch`. Does that make a difference?